# Building a React component which can be triggered like a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've come across this problem multiple times so far whilst working with React and haven't yet worked out the solution.

Let's say we have a `<Notification>` component which displays a message at the top of a page. I would like to be able to call `show()` on the component which would trigger a 2 second display of 'Message' and then hide the component after those 2 seconds. All of this functionality would be encapsulated within the component with CSS and JS Timeouts.

I understand that I could pass in 'show' via props and the component could decide to show itself, but this would mean that every parent component would need to re-implement a 2 second Timeout of the prop 'show', flipping it from true to false. I want the component to encapsulate this functionality for easy re-use.

Alternatively, equipping `<Notification>` with that functionality, then passing in `<Notification show={true}/>` quickly followed by `<Notification show={false}/>` could work but it just doesn't feel right as it's still each parent dealing with the implementation over and over again.

Perhaps the above cannot be accomplished through the 'React way of thinking' since it is preferred that components are 'dummy' where possible but this is something I would really like to achieve with React.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly what you describe : notifications with delay fadeout, etc...

The way I make it works is to have a collection, add notifications to the collection and the component listen to the collection and render itself with those entry.

The collection is responsible of the timeout before the deletion regard the fact that notification with buttons shouldn't be flushed without user interaction.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some code samples? I roughly understand what you're saying but might be clearer with code.

Comment: Sorry about that but I can't since this code is made in my daily job. But you can find more information about making your component listen to collection in [Flux examples](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a React newbie myself, so take my suggestion with a pinch of salt, as it may not be the most React-y way of doing this. But it strikes me that what you require is an ideal candidate for the publish/subscribe technique of communicating between components. That is, your Notification component subscribes to notification requests, and anything which needs to issue a notification publishes a notification request (with the message, etc., as data).

There are lots of different code samples and libraries out there for handling pub/sub. I've used Arbiter.js, which seems clean and simple and works. What you would do is set up your subscribe in 'componentWillMount' and unsubscribe in 'componentWillUnmount'. Something like this...

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    this.pubsubToken = Arbiter.subscribe('notification',function(message) {

        this.doNotification(message);
    }.bind(this));
},

componentWillUnmount: function () {
    Arbiter.unsubscribe(this.pubsubToken);
},

doNotification: function(message){
//do whatever here

}
```

Then any component needing to issue a notification would simply do this:

```
Arbiter.publish("notification", {"message":"blah"} );
```